# PHP SQL previous and next date navigation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code that I am using to show current day matches

```
<?php
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM todaysmatches where matchdate=$today") or die(mysql_error()); 

echo "<h4>$today Matches</h4> </br>";

//table
if(mysql_num_rows($data)==0){
    echo " No Matches";
}else{      
    echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <th>Match</th>
                <th>Tourmanet</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>";

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['curmatch'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['tournamentname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['matchdate'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

what I would like to get is 2 buttons for previous and next day that can go in the query and retrieve the data for that date, those buttons can be clicked multiple times not just ones

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you gotten stuck? You shouldn't just ask for us to do it for you, you need to show that you've made some effort to accomplish it.

Comment: I have tried a date picker which I thought would be easier to use and navigate but I couldn't get that input and use it in the query this is the date picker I used `http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#event-onSelect`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
//$today = date('Y-m-d');
 $firstdate = $_POST['firstdate']; // first date which is today
$seconddate = $_POST['seconddate']; //or make this some date you want

//if submit button is pressed do this
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM todaysmatches where matchdate=$today") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

echo "<h4>$today Matches</h4> </br>";

//table
if (empty($data)){
 echo " No Matches";
 }
else{

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Match</th>
<th>Tourmanet</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>";

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
 {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $info['curmatch'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $info['tournamentname'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $info['matchdate'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}

}//end submit button press
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="firstdate" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="seconddate" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

 </form>
```